# Login React Native + Firebase com erro utilizando "SwitchNavigator"

Tags: react, react-native, react-router, react-navigation

Erro ***(undefined is not a function (near '...(0, _reactNavigation.SwitchNavigator)...'))*** ao compilar aplicação.

Preciso que ao logar seja direcionado para a tela "Main".

```
import React from 'react'
import { StyleSheet, Platform, Image, Text, View } from 'react-native'
import { SwitchNavigator } from 'react-navigation'

// import the different screens
import Loading from './Loading'
import SignUp from './SignUp'
import Login from './Login'
import Main from './Main'

// create our app's navigation stack
const App = SwitchNavigator(
  {
    Loading,
    SignUp,
    Login,
    Main
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'Loading'
  }
)

export default App
```

Comment: você quer que ele seja redirecionado de onde? onde está o código que você está tentando fazer o redirecionamento? qual função está chamando?

Answer (score 0):

Primeiro tu tem que usar o `createSwitchNavigator` e nao `SwitchNavigator` segundo o switch navigator tu tem que usar combinando 2 navigators + switch pra fazer fluxos de autenticacao segue abaixo exemplo de como utilizar ele

```
import { createSwitchNavigator, createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
import Loading from './Loading'
import SignUp from './SignUp'
import Login from './Login'
import Main from './Main'

const NaoLogado = createStackNavigator({
  Login,
  SignUp,
  Loading,
}, {
  initialRouteName: 'Loading',
})

const Logado = createStackNavigator({
  Main
}, {
  initialRouteName: 'Main',
});

const criarNavigator = (condicao) => createSwitchNavigator({
  NaoLogado,
  Logado
}, {
  initialRouteName: condicao ? 'Logado' : 'NaoLogado'
});

export default criarNavigator
// No componente tu pode fazer assim

render() {
  const Router = criarNavigator(valor);

  return <Router />
}
```

Se voce tiver usando a versao 3.0 do react-navigation tu tera que usar assim usando o `createAppContainer` do react-navigation:

```
const criarNavigator = (condicao) => 
  createAppContainer(
    createSwitchNavigator(
      ...
    ),
  )
```